# What is the business term to use when describing take a business to smaller markets

Tags: business-language

Like a business used to operate in big cities/markets, now the mgmt team made a decision - avoid the saturation and competition - to take the business to smaller places where there are new opportunities and less competition. Is there a business jargon for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is [market diversification:](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/diversification.html)

> Corporate strategy:
>
> - Practice under which a firm enters a market different from its core business. Reasons for diversification include (1) reducing risk of relying on only one or few income sources, (2) avoiding cyclical or seasonal fluctuations by producing goods or services with different demand cycles, (3) achieving a higher growth rate, and (4) countering a competitor by invading the competitor's core industry or market.

(www.businessdictionary.com)

Comment: yea am aware of the diversify narrative just looking for a lingo that is specific to this going down to smaller markets/lower-tiered cities behavior.

Comment: @BenJIANG - not sure there is a specific definition, what I usually hear is : big companies are going to *tap smaller markets*.